# OpenGL 440 - controlling line thickness in frag.

Tags: opengl, glsl, line, antialiasing, vbo

I am drawing a 3D spherical grid in opengl using a VBO of vertex points and GL_LINES. What I want to achieve is to have one line - the zenith - to be brighter than the rest.

I obviously store x,y,z coords and normals, then figured I might be able to use the texture coordinates to "tag" locations where at creation - y coordinate is 0. Like so:

```
        if (round(y) == 0.0f){ 
            _varray[nr].tex[0] = -1.0; // setting the s variable (s,t texcoord),
                                       // passed in with vbo
        }
```

Now in the fragment shader I recieve this value and do:

```
if(vs_st[0] == -1){
    diffuse = gridColor*2.f;
}else{
    diffuse = gridColor;
}
```

And the results looks kind of awful:
[Print Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ycKy7.jpg)

I realize that this is propably due to the fragment shader having to interpolate between two points, can you guys think of a good way to identify the zenith line and make it brighter? I'd rather avoid using geometry shaders...

Comment: In your fragment shader, try doing `if(vs_st[0] > 0.5)` instead.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo - that would work, if the sphere was in its original position at all times - i rotate it, what can i do then?

Answer (score 0):

Solution was this:

```
if (round(y) == 0.0f) _varray[nr].tex[0] = -2; // set arb. number.
```

And then do not setthat variable **anywhere** else! then in fragment:

```
if( floor(vs_st[0]) == -2){
    diffuse = gridColor*2.f;
}else{
    diffuse = gridColor;
}
```

Dont know how neat that is, but it works.